# How to I create tranining data set (tree based) for stanford core nlp sentiment analysis from raw sentiment dataset of blog comments?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a training set of blog comments, how do I create the training data for recursive deep model?

Like the sample data

(4 (4 (2 A) (4 (3 (3 warm) (2 ,)) (3 funny))) (3 (2 ,) (3 (4 (4 engaging) (2 film)) (2 .))))

Answer (score 0):

As you show, the RNN sentiment model requires a training set of parsed language labeled with sentiment data at each tree node.

You need to **make these annotations yourself (i.e., manually)** in order to guarantee the parser quality. There are some details in [the original paper](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf) about how the training data was created by crowdsourcing. With sufficient motivation, time, and money, you could do the same.

---

A lesser alternative would be to first **use the standard parser and sentiment model to automatically label the data**, then manually fix parsing and sentiment errors. This might be tenable if the text domain you're working with is similar to the one used to train the model. Since you're working with blog comments, this is unfortunately not the case!